# how to obtain the download name from an url php coding

Tags: php, url, download, filenames

ive been trying to get the name of files from a url, i found it simple with base name
until i came urls that has no sign of the true name, intil downloaded

here is an example of the links i found

here the true name is youtubedownloadersetup272.exe
http://qdrive.net/index.php/page-file_share-choice-download_file-id_file-223658-ce-0

as you can see it shows no name until download.

ive been searching a lot, i got desperated of finding nothing, ill apreciate if someone can point me the way thanks.

i sorry to bother again but i foun this link from download.com and i dont se the filename using curl

```
<?php

function getFilename($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

 echo $data;    
preg_match("#filename=([^\n]+)#is", $data, $matches);

    return $matches[1];
}

echo getFilename("http://software-files-l.cnet.com/s/software/11/88/39/66/YouTubeDownloaderSetup272.exe?e=1302969716&h=89b64b6e8e7485eab1e560bbdf68281d&lop=link&ptype=1901&ontid=2071&siteId=4&edId=3&spi=fdc220b131cda22d9d3f715684d064ca&pid=11883966&psid=10647340&fileName=YouTubeDownloaderSetup272.exe"); 

?>
```

it returns this with echo $data

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Type: application/download
Age: 866
Date: Sat, 16 Apr 2011 10:16:54 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 08 Apr 2011 18:04:41 GMT
Content-Length: 4700823
Connection: keep-alive

if i understood the scrip you gave me it wont work because it has no filename, 
is there a way to get the name with out having to do regex or parsing the url (YouTubeDownloaderSetup272.exe?e.........), like the scrip you gave me ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `curl`, or some other library to request the file and look at the headers of the response.

You'll be looking for a header like:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=???
```

Where the question marks are the name of the file.

(You will still have to download the file, or at least look like you are downloading the file.)

Comment: you can do a `HEAD` request instead of `GET` to get the headers and not the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFilename($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match("#filename=([^\n]+)#is", $data, $matches);

    return $matches[1];
}

echo getFilename("http://qdrive.net/index.php/page-file_share-choice-download_file-id_file-223658-ce-0"); //YouTubeDownloaderSetup272.exe
```

For download.com...

```
function download_com($url){

    $filename = explode("?", $url);
    $filename = explode("/", $filename[0]);
    $filename = end($filename);

    return $filename;

}

echo download_com("http://software-files-l.cnet.com/s/software/11/88/39/66/YouTubeDownloaderSetup272.exe?e=1302969716&h=89b64b6e8e7485eab1e560bbdf68281d&lop=link&ptype=1901&ontid=2071&siteId=4&edId=3&spi=fdc220b131cda22d9d3f715684d064ca&pid=11883966&psid=10647340&fileName=YouTubeDownloaderSetup272.exe");
```

Comment: hello, thanks i was about to tell you that its not working, but i see you change it.  thanks for all the help

Comment: can you help me with this new problem of a url from download.com

Comment: @marisoldelta, regex was bad, but now it works, for download.com you don't need this, I will update my answer soon.